# R function solve: How small can the reciprocal of condition number be?

Tags: r, matrix-inverse

I have a function which takes an inverse of a matrix, say `mat`. I would like to take an inverse only if the matrix is invertible using `solve` function. So, I would like to make some check statement like;

```
if (rcond(mat) > smallnumb)
  {
  smat <- solve(mat)
  }
```

I do not want to make `smallnumb` to be too large because I want to take an inverse when I can.

My question is how small does the `smallnumb` have to be.

Comment: I would say "it depends".  You can always use SVD if you find degenerate columns.  I'd start with 1.0e-6 and play with it.

Comment: An "obvious" limit is when the inverse value gets close to the machine precision limit, e.g. `.Machine$double.eps` . But you'll almost certainly get in trouble long before that when trying to invert a near-singular matrix.

Comment: You might want to use `try` or `tryCatch` instead.